# Cannot use remote debugging for Azure Cloud Service, Symbols have not been loaded

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use the Remote Debugging from visual Studio of a Cloud Service web role and/ or Worker role.

I am using VS 2013 Ultimate with update 4.
I am using the Azure 2.6 SDK.

No matter what I do, my breakpoints have the warning, 'the breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document.'

I have tried many things based on various posts, including:

Of course I have checked the 'Remote Debugging' when deploying the cloud project.

I am using Debug Deployment.
I have confirmed using RDP that compilation debug=true is in the web.config.

I have tried both checked and unchecked for VS setting 'Enable Just My Code'.

I have added the path to my local bin folder in the Symbols dialog in VS.

I have tried choosing both WP3 and WAIISHost processes, both individually and both at the same time.

I have tried both 'Automatic' and selecting the managed .NET 4.0 4.5 in the 'Attach To' (Note that when I click Select, and it opens with the 'Automatic' radio button, none of the checkboxes are selected.  I saw a screenshot in one of the articles that showed this with 2 of the checked when Automatic was lit). All of my projects target the 4.5 Framework.  I have tried checking just 4.5 and 4.5 and Native both (which issues a warning about role restarting when debugging stops.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just redeployed (Published) again, and the only thing I changed was unchecking the 'Deployment update' checkbox.  Not sure if this was it, or just something went wrong before, however it is working now.

Comment: I have same problem, and I have no idea what's wrong